# Crystal reports viewer print dialog crash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have created a vs2010 win app that uses Crystal-reports 13.0 sp22
The app is deployed on a work-group of 5 computers
There is a printer connected to the network visible from all PCs
All PCs can print to the printer except one
This one can print from all programs eg notepad, PDF but not from my app
The user clicks on the viewers button to print, the print dialog shows up
but when print is clicked or layout tab is clicked the app crashes
[image]
[image]
Checking the event viewer I get two application errors:
Number 1:

> Application: InsuranceAgent.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.ArgumentException    at
>   System.Globalization.RegionInfo..ctor(Int32)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportPrintDialogCustomPanel.GetPaperSizeString(Double,
>   Double)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportPrintDialogCustomPanel.UpdateChoices()
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportPrintDialog.UpdateSelectedPrinterOnPanel()
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportPrintDialog.CrystalReportPrintPropertySheetDlgProc(IntPtr,
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsMessages, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr)

Number 2:

> Faulting application name: InsuranceAgent.exe, version: 2.0.6622.2791,
>   time stamp: 0x5a876a70 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.16299.248, time stamp: 0x4414ec23 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0000000000014008 Faulting process ID: 0x27fc Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d3a782bfac72fc Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\PNSoftware\Insurance Agent\InsuranceAgent.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report ID:
>   70ffc331-1923-4f03-b06e-e07935328527 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

This Happens only in this PC all others are ok and all the same win10 OS

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Thank you all in advance

Comment: PS
I tried to use different settings in page setup like checking 
No Printer (optimize for screen display) with no luck

Answer (score 0):

​After all the problem was solved
​I cannot explain why but only how !!!!!

I changed the regional settings ( the format tab )​ to English United States
​Any other setting does not work eg. English United Kingdom
​The funny thing is that on the network all other computers they have regional settings Greek and the application is working fine
​
​Would be great to have an explanation but at least at last it is working ...

All the best

Nikos